# Strange Blue markings / artifacts on Android Browser when browsing a specific website

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I am noticing strange blue markings when I visit certain webpages on Samsung galaxy note 10.1 is running android 4.1.2. This is only happening on one website and not the other. I have attached screenshots of both. I think it could be due to certain CSS or JS. Not sure what is is. Please help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxPFO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/25cNO.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an advertising blocker running. Could there be a banner add that should be showing where those blue images are?